# metrical analysis software for ancient greek

Tags: greek, software

Does anyone know any good metrical analysis software for ancient Greek? Which are the best ones and which are the most user friendly?

Comment: Do you mean a metrical theory analysis of ancient Greek stress / accent (Hayesian and similar), or do you mean an analysis of poetic meter?